# Java: ConcurrencyLevel value for ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrent-programming

Is there some optimal value for ConcurrencyLevel beyond which ConcurrentHashMap's performance starts degrading?

If yes, what's that value, and what's the reason for performance degradation? (this question orginates from trying to find out any practical limitations that a ConcurrentHashMap may have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) offers pretty detailed guidance:

> The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the optional `concurrencyLevel` constructor argument (default 16), which is used as a hint for internal sizing.
>
> The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary. Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many threads as will ever concurrently modify the table. Using a significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time, and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention. But overestimates and underestimates within an order of magnitude do not usually have much noticeable impact. A value of one is appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and all others will only read.

To summarize: **the optimal value depends on the number of expected concurrent updates.** A value within an order of magnitude of that should work well. Values outside that range can be expected to lead to performance degradation.

Comment: I've seen this doc, but it doesn't answer my question. Say I want to load-test ConcurrentHashMap. So at what value of concurrencyLevel will its performance start degrading, and why?

Comment: @shrini1000: I think it's actually fairly clear on that: the optimal value **depends on the number of expected concurrent updates**. A value within an order of magnitude of that should work well. According to the Javadoc, values outside that range can be expected to lead to performance degradation.

Comment: let me rephrase the question: what's the *max* value of concurrencyLevel that ConcurrentHashMap can take without degrading its performance (let's say those many threads are updating concurrently).

Comment: @shrini1000: I doubt there's a universal number where things work really well for `N` and grind to a halt for `N+1`. More likely the performance degradation is gradual; also, it probably depends on lots of factors. If you want to get some numbers relevant to your environment, I'd recommend setting up some benchmarks.

Comment: agreed on setting up benchmarks, but wanted to know if anybody else had done it before (Google didn't turn up with much).

Comment: There's not going to be a single constant value, @shrini1000.  If you have 1000 concurrent updates occurring simultaneously, then concurrencyLevel should be approximately 1000.  It's going to depend on your application and your hardware.

Comment: @NPE +1 for your great Answer. Could you please also explain how SPACE and Time is increased when more concurrencyLevel  is used? i could think the size will be in 2powN so after 512, it will choose 1024 may cause waste in SPACE, but how time? it should o(1) right? Also is that not possible equal increment like 8+8+.... instead of 2powN ...? and using % instead of & as masking factor?

Answer (score 5):

You have to ask yourself two questions

- how many cpus do I have?
- what percentage of the time will a **useful** program be accessing the same map?

The first question tells you the maximum number of threads which can access the map at once.  You can have 10000 threads, but if you have only 4 cpus, at most 4 will be running at once.

The second question tells you the most any of those threads will be accessing the map AND doing something useful.  You can optimise the map to do something useless (e.g. a micro-benchmark) but there is no point tuning for this  IMHO.  Say you have a useful program which uses the map a lot.  It might be spending 90% of the time doing something else e.g. IO, accessing other maps, building keys or values, doing something with the values it gets from the map.

Say you spend 10% of the time accessing a map on a machine with 4 CPUs. This means on average you will be accessing the map in 0.4 threads on average. (Or one thread about 40% of the time) In this case a concurrency level of 1-4 is fine.

In any case, making the concurrency level higher than the number of cpus you have is likely to be unnecessary, even for a micro-benchmark.

Comment: about 10000 threads example: even though atmost 4 threads can run *at the same time*, more threads can access it *concurrently*, right? E.g. a thread is pre-empted while in the middle of a put or put-if-absent operation and so on. So my question is more from this other use case.

Comment: "a thread is pre-empted while in the middle of a put" in which case its not running. It doesn't hold a lock and is not effectively accessing it.

Comment: Threads which are not running on a cpu cannot be thought of as accessing the collection.

Comment: say 'put' in turn has 3 steps in it, as s1, s2 and s3. Since put is synchronized, and if a thread is preempted after s1, then it will still hold the lock for that put operation, right?

Comment: It doesn't use synchronized but it does use Locks (unlike many other Concurrent collections)  So there is a small risk that a `put` could be interrupted while locked.  This depends on the percentage time spent inside the map. You are right that this could cause a problem in extreme micro-benchmarks.

Comment: Where I have seen the concurrency level increased is in micro-benchmarks on machines with lots of cpus e.g. hundreds. Azul have machines with 864 cores and their CTO, Cliff Click developed an optimised version of this collection for their systems http://www.azulsystems.com/products/vega/specs

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks for your answer! (upvoted) this clarifies a lot of things in my head. But this is bugging me: If most servers won't have about 16 cores I think(tm), then, why is 16 the default concurrencyLevel ?

Comment: I think I found the answer http://ria101.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/concurrenthashmap-avoid-a-common-misuse/ thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 8, `ConcurrentHashMap`'s constructor parameter for `concurrencyLevel` is [effectively unused](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java/#894), and remains primarily for backwards-compatibility.  The implementation was re-written to use the first node within each hash bin as the lock for that bin, rather than a fixed number of segments/stripes as was the case in earlier versions.

In short, starting in Java 8, don't worry about setting the `concurrencyLevel` parameter, as long as you set a positive (non-zero, non-negative) value, per the API contract.